# SortedSet transform

Tags: java, guava, comparator, compareto, sortedset

I have the following case:

```
SortedSet<MyClass> sortedSet = ...;
SortedSet<HeavyToCompare> newSet = ...;
for (MyClass m: sortedSet ){
newSet.add(m.getHeavyToCompare())    
}
```

I want to avoid reordering of the newSet because HeavyToCompare it's very expensive to compare. Rather i want to keep the insertion order (that is the same of the original set).
I understand that I can create a simple comparator that always return -1, but this breaks the contract of compareTo.
What's the best practice here? I would need something like

```
SortedSet<K> result = Sets.transformAndKeepOrder(SortedSet<T> from, Function<T, K> function)
```

UPDATE: I cannot change the SortedSet, it is a requirement

Comment: Couldn't you just use `ArrayList` instead of second `SortedSet`?

Comment: Or `LinkedHashSet`, at the very least.

Comment: thanks, but I cannot change the SortedSet, otherwise it would be no problem at all.

Comment: There isn't going to be a solution for your requirements except writing your own wrapper `SortedSet` implementation.  Guava probably wouldn't support this, because there's no way to enforce the guarantee that the resulting `SortedSet` is in order.

Comment: You are right, I ended up doing my own SortedSet

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is a `Set` that iterates in insertion order:

```
Set<HeavyToCompare> newSet = new LinkedHashSet<HeavyToCompare>();
```

However, it is not a `SortedSet`, but hopefully that is not a requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a requirement, from which my question arises.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to record the position in the `sortedSet` the object appears in. You could then compare the positions before calling the heavy compare.

How you achieve that will depend on a lot more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode a comparison order with Guava's [`Ordering.explicit`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit%28java.util.List%29). However, this produces a limited `SortedSet`. Specifically, its comparison methods (`headSet`, etc.) will work only when their arguments are members of the set. After all, `Ordering.explicit` only knows how to compare the values that you provide it. More concretely:

```
// In the real code, this values list will be computed in your loop:
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);

Comparator<Integer> comparator = Ordering.explicit(values);
SortedSet<Integer> set = Sets.newTreeSet(comparator);
set.addAll(values);
set.headSet(4); // OK: [2]
set.headSet(5); // exception: "Cannot compare value: 5"
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up Ordering.explicit. However, it does not solve my problem as the two Sets are of different type

Comment: RE: different types: You're referring to the input and output sets? That should still be OK: Just change your loop to temporarily insert the output values into a List instead of a SortedSet. Then you have a collection that (a) contains elements of the output type, (b) iterates over the elements in the desired order, and (c) doesn't require any comparisons to create. The only problem is that it's not a SortedSet. But we can fix that. Take the list you created, and pass it to Ordering.explicit. Use the resulting comparator to create a TreeSet into which you can dump the output elements. Done.